# Passing data values between two classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I guess it is quite regular issue, but for some reason I cannot find the answer on the net.

So I have a class A:

```
class A {
   const data = {...}
}
```

And a class B in a separate js file.

```
class B {
   // how can I get const data here?
}
```

Comment: Even if someone answers you, I don't think this is your real code for which you cannot guarantee the answer will work. So the code does not make sense which you have provided.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - don't complicate things by trying to judge code snippets on the merit of how 'real' they are. Just take it as a hypothetical, doesn't need to be a real-world scenario as long as it is specific enough. Not specific? Then request clarity.

Comment: @Barth - in which context? Web? If so, depending on what it is you want to share, a variable on the page will be globally accessible to all. Whether this makes sense design-wise depends on the requirements.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ then why are you asking the above question to OP if you think I am complicating the things.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - what are you talking about? We were both making 2 entirely different points!? I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: @JayMee Yes, in the web context. What is the syntax then to get a variable value from classB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use composition, and instantiate new instance of class `A` inside of constructor of class `B`.

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.data = { foo: "bar" };
  }
}

class B {    
  constructor() {
    this.instanceOfA = new A();
    console.log(this.instanceOfA.data);
  }
}

console.log(new B());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if in class A my variable is located in the body(I mean not in the constructor)?

Comment: I don't think that's valid syntax of ES6. Or do you use some other version?

Answer (score 1):

Here is data passed by function/event in two class:

```
   class A {
     constructor(name) {
       console.log(name)
     }
    }

    class B {    
      y(){
        return "ram"
      }
    }

    let resultFromB = (new B().y());
    new A(resultFromB)
```